# String date to java date conversion

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string date something like below , I want to convert it in to `java.util.Date`.

```
String fromDate = "03/19/2009";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
java.util.Date dtt = df.parse(fromDate);
System.out.println("the date is "+dtt);
```

But I am getting out put as **Thu Mar 19 00:00:00 IST 2009**, but I need it as `03/19/2009`.
Please help me out.

Comment: print statement should be as System.out.println("the date is "+df.format(dtt));

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same DateFormat and its [SimpleDateFromat.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) to get the desired output.

```
String fromDate = "03/19/2009";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
java.util.Date dtt = df.parse(fromDate);
System.out.println("the date is " + df.format(dtt));
```

Comment: df.format(dtt) is working fine , but it is returing string, I need it to be java.util.Date.

Comment: But the Date is already correctly stored in the `dtt` variable, everything is fine and the princess is saved. The `toString()` is just a textual representation of the Date, which can be modified by the DateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it again to the format you desire.

What you are currently printing is the value returned by the Data objects toString method.

Answer (score 0):

You code works well. `dtt` actually holds the **correct** `Date` value.

When you print a `Date`, it uses `toString()`.

If you want to print it in a specific format, you need to use another `SimpleDateFormat` and call [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Call method `format` on the SimpleDateFormat instance `df`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String DateStr="03/19/2009";
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

**output** 03/19/2009

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a `date` not converted to `string`, so your result is correct, but if you want to print it as `String`, you shall reformat it as:

```
System.out.println("the date is " + df.format(dtt));
```

Comment: Hi all thanks for your help , finally i need to java.util.date after formatting..